# Sesame Chicken with Gravy

Tags: chicken, chinese-cuisine, gravy

Okay, so this is going to be one of "those" questions.

There was a Chinese restaurant in my town when I was younger. It went out of business, reopened out of town, sold to new owners and they have no idea what I'm talking about. When it was in my town, me and my dad used to get the same thing every time. It was sesame chicken. It wasn't the standard sesame chicken you get most places with a sticky glaze on it, though.

I'm trying to remember back, over 20 years, when I was too young to be paying that close attention. I can't remember if it had any sauce on it or not. I want to say that it was just fried chicken with sesame seeds sprinkled on top and the gravy on the side. That really set it apart though. He would serve it with a brown gravy we'd pour over the top. I remember it being pretty good gravy and I remember liking the sesame chicken with the gravy, way better than with the overly sweet and sticky glaze.

My questions is, does this sound like a normal dish to anyone that I might be able to duplicate at home, or is this some one off that just happened at this restaurant. Maybe the gravy was for something else and he'd just serve it with the sesame chicken.

The closest I can find is a couple of recipes for "chinese gravy". I have no idea what it tastes like, but the color and consistency looks correct from what I remember and it was a chinese restaurant, so it could be possible. It's just that when I google 'sesame chicken chinese gravy', nothing even close pops up as a recipe.

So does this sound like a dish anyone else has had? If so, I'd like some direction in finding a recipe to replicate it. It was really good. Thanks guys/gals.

Comment: There is a site - The Woks of Life {https://thewoksoflife.com/} run by a Chinese-American family (husband, wife & 2 adult daughters) with restaurant experience and extensive Chinese food knowledge. You could try writing to Bill and ask {bill@thewoksoflife.com}

Comment: You could also try the recipes for "Chinese gravy".  The chicken and the sesame seed part is easily reproducible.  Put them together and see if it brings back some memories.

Comment: It's possible that this was a regional chinese restaurant, and not an "American Chinese" restaurant.  If so, your memory of what else was on the menu might help us figure out what region the cuisine is from.

Comment: Might it have been a brown sauce? [Google Chinese brown sauce](https://www.google.com/search?ei=D1ZwW9rlE8PKjwTclq6gBA&q=chinese+brown+sauce&oq=chinese) and you'll find quite few recipes and articles that may help